# Cannot decode HTML entity in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters, html-entities, html-encode

I want this string:

```
"Hartn&#195;&#164;ckigkeit zahlt sich aus"
```

Getting converted to this:

```
Hartnäckigkeit zahl sich aus
```

I tried this:

```
html_entity_decode( "Hartn&#195;&#164;ckigkeit zahlt sich aus", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```

But did not succeed.

Comment: try to use `base64_enconde()`

Comment: What output do you get now and what do you expect?

Comment: @bcesars `base64_enconde()` since when is this a php build in function?

Comment: @Rizier123 I expect this: Hartnäckigkeit zahlt sich aus

Comment: @Rizier123. I'm not sure if I understood your question but: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-encode.php. YES. There is a  function for this. Actually its `base64_encode()`. And then you can use `base64_decode()`

Comment: @user998163 are you sure this html entities are correct? &#195; and &#164;

Comment: That is not the HTML entity for "ä". I'd say you're looking at HTML encoded garbage produced by mishandled encodings.

Answer (score 2):

Your encoded string seems off from the beginning, and may have been created somewhere by wrongfully HTML-encoding an UTF-8 string as ISO-8859-1:

Example (source code in UTF-8 format):

```
echo htmlentities(
    "Hartnäckigkeit zahlt sich aus", ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1'
), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Hartn&Atilde;&curren;ckigkeit zahlt sich aus
```

(same as `Hartn&#195;&#164;ckigkeit zahlt sich aus`)

Use this to decode it:

```
echo html_entity_decode(
    "Hartn&#195;&#164;ckigkeit zahlt sich aus",
    ENT_COMPAT,
    'ISO-8859-1'
);
```

Output:

```
Hartnäckigkeit zahlt sich aus
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your output doing this:

```
$test = "Hartn&#228;ckigkeit zahlt sich aus";
echo html_entity_decode($test, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

Your entity codes seem off.

Answer (score -1):

You can use utf8_encode ( $data );

See more about encode here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php